# How to solve this Facebook Audience network bug causing for version update?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

After updating Facebook Audience Network SDK version to 4.26.0, my app is facing lots of crash because of the below issue according to Firebase crash report.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/<app-package-name>/databases/ads.db
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference (SQLiteClosable.java:55)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction (SQLiteDatabase.java:568)
com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$2.a ()
com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$2.b ()
com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$1.a ()
com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$1.doInBackground ()
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:292)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's a bug in 4.26.0 of Facebook AudienceNetwork SDK. I submitted it to Facebook and got a reply that they are investigating, and taking a lot of time doing so - see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/213725762497306/

The only work-around for this bug I found was to downgrade to version 4.25.0, but it has its own problems, for example some of the users of my app hit now a bug

> IllegalStateException: register failed, the sensor listeners size has
>   exceeded the maximum limit 128

Other developers reported some arithmetic overflow bug with 4.25.0, which I have not seen so far.

Comment: 4.24.0 is the last stable version. I had to downgrade twice for last two updates.